# how to make slide animation?

Tags: jquery, css

css part

```
 body
{
background-color:black;
padding:0;
margin:0;
overflow:hidden;
}   
  #accordion {
   display:none;
       position:absolute;   
   left:89%;   
       margin-top:400px;
       width:174px;
   height:150px; 
   list-style:none;

  }

 #logpop
{
 display:none;
 position:absolute; 
 left:91%;   
 margin-top:400px;
 width:174px;
 height:150px; 

}


   <!-- login -->
   <div id="logpop">
     <div  class="logpop_box">
     <div class="form">
    <input class="input_box" name="email" type="text" placeholder="aaa"/><br/>
    <input class="input_box" name="pass" type="password" placeholder="*****"/>
            <br/>
    <button id="btn1">Login</button>
          </div>
         </div>
    </div>
 <!-- accordian menu-->
    <ul id="accordion">
<li>
    <a href="#" class="item popular" rel="popular"></a>
    <ul id="inchat" class="list_friends">
    <li class="ch0"><img src="img/49992_720384020_1896998575_q.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="ch1"><img src="img/48983_615523712_8495_q.jpg" /></li>
        <li class="ch2"><img src="img/41621_717814907_4472_q.jpg" /></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#" class="item category" rel="category"></a>
    <ul id="inchannel">
        <li class="icha0"><img  src="img/41403_1434825607_37944358_q.jpg">Jae Jung</li>
        <li class="icha1"><img  src="img/48983_615523712_8495_q.jpg"></li>
        <li class="icha2"><img  src="img/41621_717814907_4472_q.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</li>

 </ul>
```

there is video running in the background and I want to make login box slice from right out of screen to left and when user clicks on button it slides to right out of screen and accordion menu slide in right out of screen to left. I wonder css for login box and accordion has right position(positioning on right screen middle) and how to implement Jquery to make sliding animation effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4FS2u/1/)

HTML

```
<input id="btnStart" type="button" value="Start" />
<div id="slider">Login</div>
<div id="accordion">
   <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
   <div>First content</div>
   <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
   <div>Second content</div>
</div>​
```

CSS

```
body{
    overflow: hidden;
}
#slider{
    width: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(200,200,200);
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 50px;
    right: -100px;
}
#accordion{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 20px;
    left: -100px;
}
input{
    padding: 3px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$("#accordion").accordion();
$("#btnStart").click(function(e) {
    $("#slider").animate({
        "right": "+=" + $(window).width() / 2 + "px"
    }, "1000");
});
$("#slider").click(function(e) {
    $("#slider").animate({
        "right": "-=" + $(window).width() / 2 + "px"
    }, "1000");
    $("#accordion").animate({
        "left": "+=" + $(window).width() / 2 + "px"
    }, "1000");
});​​
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery provides the .slideDown & .slideUp functions to slide an elements from bottom-to-top or vice versa, but it doesn't provide one to slide ltr or rtl.

But [this](http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions) is a short tutorial that covers how you can do it with minimal code.

Comment: is there any way to use animate function to make it slide left or right?

Comment: read the 'Horizontal Slides' section in the tutorial i proposed you.